# Send an email I want it isn't received

Tags: email

:)

I searched for any solution but I found nothing. I'd send an email like as follows:

```
To: Recipient1@domain.com CC: Recipient2@domain.com
```

but I'd want that Recipient1 does NOT receive the email, while Recipient2 does. In this way, Recipient2 thinks I sent the email also to Recipient1 but, actually, Recipient1 received nothing.

Is it possible?
Thank you very much.

Comment: That's not possible from the client side. If you add an address to `to` or `cc` or `bcc` the server will try to send to that address. If you have control over the Server, you may be able to block it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding special characters to the first email address, like a non breaking space, or a similar looking character from another character set, you may find a way to generate a failing address while not really displaying it!
I know it works that way with URL and some spam e-mails...